# Tabela não esta ficando com scrooll horizontal

Tags: php, javascript, css

então pessoal, tenho uma pagina puxando dados do banco para a tabela, porém a tabela não fica com o scrooll vertical ao ficar maior do que o elemento... segundo documentação do bootstrap 4.0 deveria usar como esta no codigo abaixo, mas não funciona de nenhuma maneira...

esta é a parte da pagina, que tem um menu a esquerda....

```
<div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">

    <!-- Header-->
    <header id="header" class="header">

        <div class="header-menu">

            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <a id="menuToggle" class="menutoggle pull-left"><i class="fa fa fa-tasks"></i></a> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <div class="user-area dropdown float-right">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="sair.php"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Sair</a>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header><!-- /header -->
    <!-- Header-->

    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="page-header float-left">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>Consulta de Clientes</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                </div>

               <!-- TABELA-->

            <div class="content mt-3">

            <div style="overflow-y: auto; max-height:600px;">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
           <input class="form-control" id="myInput" name="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered">
         <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr> 
            <th scope="col">Código</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Cpf</th>
            <th scope="col">Endereço</th>
            <th scope="col">Número</th>
                <th scope="col">Cidade</th>
                <th scope="col">UF</th>
            <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
            <th scope="col">Telefone</th>
            <th scope="col">Telefone 2</th>
        </tr>
         </thead>
                    <?php 
                while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                    $codigo = $dados['cod'];
                $nome = $dados['nome'];
                $cpf = $dados['cpf'];
                $endereco = $dados['endereco'];
                $numero = $dados['numero'];
                $cidade = $dados['cidade'];
                $uf = $dados['uf'];
                $email = $dados['email'];
                $telefone = $dados['telefone'];
                $telefone2 = $dados['telefone2'];
                ?>
     <tbody id="myTable" name="myTable">
        <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $codigo ?></th>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $nome ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $cpf ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $endereco ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $numero ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $cidade ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $uf ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $email ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $telefone ?></td>
         <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $telefone2 ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

o problema é que a div com classe table-responsive antes da table não funciona, nem mesmo colocando a div com

style="overflow-x:auto;"

funciona sómente se eu colocar assim:

style="overflow-x: auto; max-width:1020px;"

porém se o monitor for maior não vai ampliar o tamanho dela

Comment: Bom dia amigão beleza ? Para tornar nossa vida mais fácil você poderia colocar um exemplo dessa tabela já populada com dados ? Assim podemos te ajudar no que realmente importa para você no momento sem ter que ficar adivinhando ou mockando seu código PHP, se você apenas gerar a tabela no seu navegador e pressionar F12 para inspecionar o elemento dela você já vai conseguir a informação que queremos para te ajudar ai só editar a pergunta, valeu !

Comment: Olá, tudo bem? Você ressaltou já tentou utilizar tamanho fixo, mas e unidades relativas? com a mesma solução vou pode aplicar a seguinte condição, use o width: 100vw, desta forma ele vai pegar o tamanho da view. Aqui tem uma abordagem mais detalhada sobre o tema: https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/unidades-de-medidas-css.php

Comment: ola getulio, tentei mas da no mesmo, fica até pior .... usando tanto px quanto vw ele perde a função de se auto ajeitar se a tela for maior